# Getting unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction error - postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, docker, psycopg2

I am having a peculiar issue with adding some default data to a postgres db that is running as a microservice.

My setup:

- container with latest PG - have an init.db that creates a table if not already present.
- another container that runs a python script to populate the table in the PG container, I am using a csv file to get the data to be written into the db table.

Fact: The csv file has about 130000+ entries to write.

Problem:

If the PG microservice is running and I run the python script locally on my pc to connect and populate data in PG microservice, everything works as expected.
But, If I run both microservices using a docker-compose, then I get error in the PG microservice container:

*ERROR: unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction*

*FATAL:  terminating connection because protocol synchronization was lost*

*LOG:  could not send data to client: Broken pipe*

This is my python script to write data from a csv into the database using psycopg2:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
try:
    DB_CONNECTION = psycopg2.connect(f'host={host} port={port} dbname={database} user={user} password={password}')
    DB_CURSOR = DB_CONNECTION.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    DB_CONNECTED = not DB_CONNECTION.closed and not DB_CURSOR.closed
    print(f'db connection succeeded: {DB_CONNECTED}')
    if DB_CONNECTED:
        with open(sql_file, 'r') as f:
            query = f.read()
            DB_CURSOR.execute(query)
            DB_CONNECTION.commit()
            DB_CURSOR.execute("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'test_table';")
            DB_CONNECTION.commit()
            if DB_CURSOR.rowcount == 1:
                DB_CURSOR.execute("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM test_table;")
                DB_CONNECTION.commit()
                res = DB_CURSOR.fetchone()
                DB_CONNECTION.commit()
                if res['count'] == 0:
                    print(f'the table test_table is not populated, adding from {csv_file}')
                    sio = StringIO()
                    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
                    column_names = df.columns.tolist()
                    df.to_csv(sio, header=False, index=False)
                    sio.seek(0)

                    DB_CURSOR.copy_from(
                        file=sio,
                        table='test_table',
                        sep=',',
                        columns=df.columns.tolist(),
                        null=''
                    )
                    sio.close()
                    DB_CONNECTION.commit()
                    DB_CURSOR.close()
                    DB_CONNECTION.close()
                else:
                    if DB_CURSOR:
                        DB_CURSOR.close()
                    if DB_CONNECTION:
                        DB_CONNECTION.close()
                    print(f'the table test_table is present and is populated with {res["count"]} entries')

except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError, KeyboardInterrupt) as error:
    print(f"Error: {error}")
    if DB_CONNECTION:
        DB_CONNECTION.rollback()
        DB_CONNECTION.close()
```

This is my compose file:

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  pg-db:
    image: pg-db-image
    container_name: pg-db
    environment:
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=test-db
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - pg-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-d", "test-db" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  db-helper:
    image: db-helper-image
    container_name: db-helper
    environment: 
      - DB_HOST=pg-db
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_NAME=test-db
      - DB_USER=user
      - DB_PASSWORD=password
      - SRC_CSV=/db-files/test_data.csv
      - INIT_SQL=/db-files/init-db.sql
      - COL_NAMES=/db-files/column_names.txt
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      pg-db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

I have already tried setting autocommit on the connection to true, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you for any pointers/ solutions!

Comment: What is the output of docker-compose for db-helper?

Comment: You see logs on the Postgres container but connection is closed by db-helper. `tcp timeout` settings like `tcpKeepAlive`(if there is any) on db-helper image might help. Also, the client you use on db-helper might affect.